# Extracting data from a form into a text file

Tags: php

i want to place the contents of values from a form into a text file. When an option is changed in the form and submit button is clicked, the user is taken to another page where info about the company's address, website and so are displayed line after line like so:

Member Search Results:

Company
800-555-555
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Website: http://example.com

Though the text file shows up blank. How do i go about achieving my desired result?
My code:

```
<html>
<form action="http://*****.com/business_detail_framed.asp" method="post" name="b1">
<Select Name="select_business" onChange="b1.input1.value=b1.select_business[this.selectedIndex].text">
<option value="5102" name="float">Company One</option>
<option value="5053" name="float">Company Two</option>
<option value="5091" name="float">Company 3</option>
</select>
<input value="Submit" type="submit" onchange="this.form.submit()">;
</form>

<?php

file_put_contents("businessinfo.txt", $_POST['float'], FILE_APPEND);

$g = file_get_contents("businessinfo.txt");
echo $g;

$r = $_REQUEST['float'];
$r .= $_POST['float'];

echo $r;


?>
```

Comment: Why are you writing to a file rather than a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` attribute of your `<select>` element is `select_business`.  You should be using `$_POST['select_business']` rather than `$_POST['float']`.

An HTML `<select>` element will pass its value in the form post by its own `name` attribute, rather than by any name attributes on its associated `<option>`s.

You should also check if the the `$_POST` has been submitted before doing the actual file write. I've also added a line break for readability in the output file.

```
if (isset($_POST['select_business'])) {
  file_put_contents("businessinfo.txt", $_POST['select_business'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: I just tested your example and the text file still shows up blank. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see in `var_dump($_POST)`? And what's the purpose of the `onchange` function in the `<select>`?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['select_business']);` comes up NULL, and i removed the onchange function from the form as well, and it still works.

Comment: @Brinard Is the form action correct? You have a file ending in `asp` ="http://*****.com/business_detail_framed.asp".

Comment: Yea it's correct, that .asp file sets the connection to a database that holds these records and displays them in a certain format. I am able to see these records by clicking the submit button, but i need to extract the data to a text file. I just included 3 options in the form as a test for the rest of the process. The contents of the .asp file is here if you need to see it. http://pastebin.com/BSUqBX8k

Comment: @Brinard But `$_POST` won't be set on _this_ page if your form action points to a different asp script.  If you need to use the post values on this PHP script, the form action has to point to _this_ script.

Comment: Well this was a very hopeful alternative for me to retrieve the business info from that database. But i don't know, do you have any suggestions...solutions ? I've looked all over for helped, try everything i could in my knowledge base so far.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really writing to file. Here is an example on how to

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);
```

You also need to able to tell if you have submitted before you write.

So I would have something like this:

```
<html>
<form method="post" name="b1">
<Select Name="select_business" onChange="b1.input1.value=b1.select_business[this.selectedIndex].text">
<option value="5102" name="float">Company One</option>
<option value="5053" name="float">Company Two</option>
<option value="5091" name="float">Company 3</option>
</select>
<input value="Submit" type="submit" onchange="this.form.submit()">;
</form>

<?php

if ($_REQUEST['Submit']) {

$fp = fopen('businessinfo.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'selected_business: ' . $_REQUEST['select_business']);
fclose($fp);

header="location http://*****.com/business_detail_framed.asp";

?>
```

Comment: Actually, the function used by the OP is identical to using fopen, fwrite and fclose. [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: I tried this method as well, and data still isn't written to the file. Any suggestions? Had to remove the header line because i prompted a Parse error.

Comment: I am such a newb, I think I accidentlly edited Michael's answer instead of mine. I am very sorry about that Michael.